# bsc get transaction list by address Web3 (realtime,socket)

Tags: node.js, web3js, binance-smart-chain

How can I track transactions of a wallet in the bsc network instantly?
(I am thinking of using web3 js.)

I don't want to do it with the api on BSCscan.
As far as I know, it does not show it instantly.

Answer (score 5):

**Native** BNB transactions:

You can subscribe to [newBlockHeaders](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders), which will emit an event each time a new block is mined. Using the block number or hash, you can get the [list of transactions](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getblock) in the block. Your app can then filter only transactions that are relevant to your watched address.

---

**Token** transactions:

Subscribe to [logs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs) and filter the `topics` reflecting only the `Transfer` event to/from your watched address. In this case, you can perform the filter as a part of the subscription parameters, so that your app doesn't have to handle unnecessary data.

---

Edit: Provider `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/` that you used in your other answer gives error "Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider". Which means you need to use a different provider that supports subscriptions or configure your own node.

Comment: i'm very new on this... Unfortunately I couldn't... I could not find a ws provider recommended by bscscan. Where can I access this? I've been searching for a week, but I haven't found any information...

Not:I'm trying to keep track of other wallets...

Comment: When you become a member of newBlockHeaders, more than 100 action lists come. Each new block and searching for the wallet address in them costs a lot. 

when i subscribe to logs; I can't filter the wallet address. Only token addresses can be filtered. 

When I become a member of pendingTransactions, I can withdraw transactions from there, but I cannot record the transactions of the wallet I want.

Comment: ```

`
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, txHash) => {
    if (err)  throw(err);
})
.on("data", function(txHash){
    web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash, (err, returnedValue) => {
        if (returnedValue?.from === address || returnedValue?.to === address) {
            console.log('TransactionHash:',returnedValue);
        }
    })
});

```